# Python - creating a class that locks objects using threading.lock()

Tags: python, multithreading, locking

Trying to create a class that can lock objects using threading.lock:

```
class ObjectLock(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._lock = threading.Lock()
        self._value = False
    def __str__(self):
        self.acquire() 
        try: 
            if(self._value):
                return self._value
            else:
                return self._value
        finally: 
            self.release() 
    def __enter__(self):
        self.acquire()
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.release()
    def acquire(self):   
        self._lock.acquire()
    def release(self):
        self._lock.release() 
    def locked(self):
        return self._lock.locked()

lock = ObjectLock()

print(lock)
with lock:
    print (lock)
```

The issue is that I'm trying to implement "with". If a method is called within a "with" block (such as **str**, the lock is re-aquired...which is bad. Do I have to create a seperate set of methods to call when I know I am working within a lock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I don't see why `__str__` needs to acquire the lock, so I think the premise is moot.

If you are certain that the internal locking is desirable, consider using a re-entrant lock, e.g. [`threading.RLock`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.RLock). This way a single thread will be able to acquire the lock as many times as it desires without deadlocking.

Comment: you may have seen the code before I re-edited it. self._value is independant of the locked state

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `threading.Lock`, use [`threading.Rlock`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#rlock-objects).  This is a reentrant lock, which allows the same thread to acquire the lock multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Use a reentrant lock (threading.RLock)

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to create a seperate set of methods to call when I know I am
>   working within a lock?

No. This has already been done for you. The `threading.RLock` class (reentrant lock) takes care of this for you, and it implements the same interface as `Lock`.

The `R` character will magically wave your problems away.